# To get the ID of the button user clicked

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am using Jeditable in my JSP to edit the contect of table. I have created additional button apart from OK and Cancel using

```
submit    : '<button type="submit" class="ok" id="ok" value="ok">OK</button> <button type="submit" class="gotourl" id="res" value="Reset">Go To URL</button>'
```

But i am not able to distinguish which button user just clicked, whether its Ok or Cancel. Trying for last 4 days.....below is my full code...

```
$('.edit_area').editable('http://131.247.19.103:80/trimms_1/parameters.action', { 
                                         type      : 'textarea',
                                         cancel    : 'Cancel',
                                         callback : function(value, settings) {

                                         window.location.reload();
                                        },
                                         submit    : '<button type="submit" class="ok" id="ok" value="ok">OK</button> <button type="submit" class="gotourl" id="res" value="Reset">Go To URL</button>',
                                         third     : 'Alert!',
                                         indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
                                         id : '$(this).attr("id")',
                                         submitdata : function() {
                                         var id2 = '${param.city}';

                                         return {city: id2, tableid: $(this).closest('table').attr('id'),
                                         rowid: $(this).parent().index(),button: selectedId}},
                                         tooltip   : 'Click to edit....',
                                         name : 'newvalue'

                                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

`var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));`---this will get the column id

`tableid: $(this).closest('table').attr('id')`--this will get the table id...................

`rowid: $(this).parent().index()`--this will get the row id of table being edited....